# In GWT, How can I get all attributes of an element in the HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I can't see any method on the com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element class that allows me to get all attributes of an element node. Have I missed anything?

Presumably I can get the attributes array of the underlying Javascript object by dropping into native code? I know the results are browser-dependent, but there seem to be known workarounds for that. I haven't dived much into native JS, so if someone can show me how to do it, that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked for a convenience method in GWT, but was surprised that I couldn't find one.

> Presumably I can get the attributes array of the underlying Javascript object by dropping into native code? I know the results are browser-dependent, ...

Yes, with [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI), you can define a method that returns the element's "attributes" property as a suitable Java object:

```
public static native JsArray<Node> getAttributes(Element elem) /*-{
   return elem.attributes;
}-*/;
```

You can use it like this:

```
final JsArray<Node> attributes = getAttributes(element);
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length(); i ++) {
    final Node node = attributes.get(i);
    String attributeName = node.getNodeName();
    String attributeValue = node.getNodeValue();
    ...
}
```

Comment: minor point;  elem.attributes is not an array (although it can be accessed like one) - it is actually a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap